# how to combine 2 json object into one json object with 2 arrays

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json

so I have a discord bot that will take your name and instagram and then put that into a json file(WIP)
I just want to figure out how I can keep my one json file and add another json object to it

```
json start
    {
  "howToUse": ",,photos {name} {instagram}",
  "date": "April 8, 2021",
  "members": [
    {
      "name": "Nick",
      "instagram": "test"
    }    
  ]
}
```

then they input name: "Jimmy" and instagram: "iLoveCode<3"
i want the json file at the end to look like:

```
json end
{
  "howToUse": ",,photos {name} {instagram}",
  "date": "April 8, 2021",
  "members": [
    {
      "name": "Nick",
      "instagram": "test"
    },
    {
      "name": "Jimmy"
      "instagram": "iLoveCode<3"
    }
  
  ]
}
```

I have tried to take the beginning json and then save that to a array and then make another array to add to the orginal then push the two together

```
fs = require('fs');
var name = 'Assets/signup.json';
var m = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(name).toString());
var originalJSON = m.members
console.log(originalJSON)
let addMember = [{name: 'Drew', instagram: 'og_300_hemi'}];
let finialJSON = originalJSON.push(addMember);
console.log(addMember)
console.log(finialJSON)
```

but when i console.log finialJSON it just says 2 and not
[{name: "Nick", instagram: "test" }, {name: "Jimmy", instagram: "iLoveCode<3"}]

Comment: I think you wrote inappropriate statement let addMember = [{name: 'Drew', instagram: 'og_300_hemi'}]; =>  let addMember = {name: 'Drew', instagram: 'og_300_hemi'};

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use below script. Hopefully it will resolve problem.

```
const test = {
  "howToUse": ",,photos {name} {instagram}",
  "date": "April 8, 2021",
  "members": [
    {
      "name": "Nick",
      "instagram": "Sex"
    }    
  ]
}
const member = {
      "name": "Jimmy",
      "instagram": "JimSex"
    }    
test.members.push(member)
console.log(test);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this to get the answer you want.

```
const m = {
  howToUse: ',,photos {name} {instagram}',
  date: 'April 8, 2021',
  members: [
    {
      name: 'Nick',
      instagram: 'test'
    },
    {
      name: 'Jimmy',
      instagram: 'iLoveCode<3'
    }

  ]
}
const originalJSON = m.members
const addMember = [{ name: 'Drew', instagram: 'og_300_hemi' }]
const finalJSON = originalJSON
console.log('finalJSON:', finalJSON)
finalJSON.push(addMember[0])
console.log('finalJSONEnd:', finalJSON)
```

Adding a code snippet too for the ref:

```js
const m = {
  howToUse: ',,photos {name} {instagram}',
  date: 'April 8, 2021',
  members: [
    {
      name: 'Nick',
      instagram: 'test'
    },
    {
      name: 'Jimmy',
      instagram: 'iLoveCode<3'
    }

  ]
}
const originalJSON = m.members
const addMember = [{ name: 'Drew', instagram: 'og_300_hemi' }]
const finalJSON = originalJSON
console.log('finalJSON:', finalJSON)
finalJSON.push(addMember[0])
console.log('finalJSONEnd:', finalJSON)
```